# How come a project still runs and builds if the dependency is not satisfied as in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I created a React app, and to check the behaviors for `Gemfile` and `package.json`, I changed one line in `package.json` from

```
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

to

```
"react": "^17.14.0",
```

as of writing, React 17 doesn't exist yet.  But

```
npm start
```

and

```
npm run-script build
```

both still work.  Both `yarn start`, `yarn build` also worked.  To compare the behavior, when I do `rails start` with a modified `Gemfile` with some version of `rails` that doesn't exist (such as Rails 7.0), it won't start at all.  How does this work with `npm` and `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The user defined scripts `start` and `build` are executed but they don't trigger yarn/npm to inspect the dependency tree.

Node itself will load the package name from `node_modules/`. Package versions are not inspected at runtime.

An `npm install` or `yarn` will fail as they will attempt to install the missing package.